# JSF Composite component and selectItems

Tags: java, jsf-2, composite-component

I have been playing around with composite components and I ran into something I could not figure out. Without using a composite component I would have something like this:

```
<h:outputText value="Some Label:"/>
<h:selectOneMenu">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 1"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 2"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 3"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I essentially turned that snippet into a composite component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

  <!-- INTERFACE -->
  <composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="label" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="options" required="true"/>      
  </composite:interface>

  <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->          
  <composite:implementation>
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.label}"/>
    <h:selectOneMenu style="width:140px;">
        <f:selectItem value="#{cc.attrs.options}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>  
  </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Now here is where I am stumped. I know I could put the list of items I want to use in the component in a backing bean and use it like this:

```
<util:dropdown label="Some Label:" options="#{backingBean.list}"/>
```

The real question is if there is a way to pass in the options without having to use a backing bean? I guess something like:

```
<util:dropdown label="Some Label:" options="Item 1, Item 2, Item 3"/>
```

or maybe

```
<util:dropdown label="Some Label:" options="#{backingBean.list}">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 1"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 2"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 3"/>
</util:dropdown>
```

Note: obviously those two do not work or I would not be asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The real question is if there is a way to pass in the options without having to use a backing bean? I guess something like:*
>
> ```xml
> <util:dropdown label="Some Label:" options="Item 1, Item 2, Item 3"/>
> ```

You can use the JSTL [`fn:split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/fn/split.fn.html) to split them into a `String[]`. The `<f:selectItems>` also accepts that as `value`. I'd only remove the spaces around the comma in the `options` attribute.

```xml
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
...

<h:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{fn:split(cc.attrs.options, ',')}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

---

> *or maybe*
>
> ```xml
> <util:dropdown label="Some Label:">
>     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 1"/>
>     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 2"/>
>     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item 3"/>
> </util:dropdown>
> ```

You can use [`<composite:insertChildren>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/composite/insertChildren.html) in the composite component to declare the location where the composite component's children have to be inserted.

```xml
<h:selectOneMenu>
    <composite:insertChildren />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Say that I need the composite component to insert two different sets of children in two different places - how would I accomplish this otherwise? I would have to use the first option only. I tried to put the f:selectItems in a facet and then render that facet in the composite component, but that also does not work. In  the case of a non-composite component, ie just using ui:decorate, I can specify multiple ui:defines to ui:insert multiple children by name. Why do composite components not have this feature?

Comment: @GreenieMeanie: composites support facets.